# Django GenericForeignKey in the admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    text = models.TextField()
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = generic.GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')

class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 40)
    comments = generic.GenericRelation(Comment)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

In the Django admin I would if possibile, under the "Comments" page, see the `__unicode__` of the content object, for example can be Product.

Something this:

**All comments**

Comment 1 - to a Product - Foo Bar (**unicode** of Product) - timestamp

Comment 2 - to a UserProfile - Foo Bar (**unicode** of UserProfile) - timestamp

etc.

Ideas for *admin.py*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest adding **unicode** method to Comment model:

```
def __unicode__(self):
    return 'Comment %s - to  a %s - %s' % (self.pk, self.content_type, self.content_object.__unicode__(), self.timestamp)
```

If you are using standart ModelAdmin, then there is no need to change admin.py.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. How can I show the method `__unicode__` in a model admin page's field?

Comment: You mean when using list_display?:  `list_display('__unicode__',)`